# Remove file in a tar, with wildcard and exception

Tags: bash, unix, shell, tar

I have a tarball, and i want to remove all .tcl, .bat , .log files **except** pkgIndex.tcl in it.

if i do

```
tar --delete -f mytarball.tar --wildcards *{.tcl,.log,.bat}
```

my pkgIndex.tcl will be deleted, how to put that as exception in my pattern wildcard?

Just tried

```
tar  --delete -f mytarball.tar --wildcards *{.tcl,.log}  --exclude=*pkgIndex.tcl
```

and

```
tar  --delete -f mytarball.tar --wildcards *{.tcl,.log}  --exclude=pkgIndex.tcl
```

To no avail...

Comment: Maybe a little obvious, but have you tried the `--exclude` option? Also this should be on `superuser.com` instead.

Comment: oh, ok, .my bad..i overlooked that one..

Comment: Just tried, didn't work, it still gets removed.

Comment: You are quoting/escaping your wildcards/braces?

Comment: the wildcard part shd be correct. Only the exclude part got problem.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like GNU tar ignores --exclude when you use --delete.

You can do `tar tf mytarball.tar --wildcards *{.tcl,.log} | grep -v pkgIndex.tcl | tar --delete -f mytarball.tar -T -` instead.  That will list all of the files matching *.tcl or *.log, grep for everything *but* pkgIndex.tcl, and pipe the list back into tar which will remove those files from the tarball.

Comment: Instead of using `grep`, `--exclude` can be used with `tar t`.